# Ubuntu takes longer when starting and shutting down

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

I use ubuntu 14.04.1. Since some days ago, it takes upon 1 minute in a dos-mode "login" until it starts, then the ambience theme in unity seems gone but it returns after a few minutes,and then when shutting down it stays around 1 minute saying "will halt now" until it shuts down, what can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bleachbit program to clear out your OS of junk files, might help.

Also check if the OS is upto date:

Sudo apt-get update